# append data to JSON object issue

Tags: php, json

I am trying to add data to JSON object. The output result doesn't show appended data "people3". Could you please let me know if I am doing right.

```
$postArray = array(
    "persons" =>  array(
        "person" => array(
                 "i_date"=> $DatabaseDate,
              "i_location"=>$_POST["location"],
              "i_summary"=>$_POST["summary"]
        ),
        "people" => array(
                "people1"=> array(
                       "first_name"=> $_POST["first-1"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-1"]
                      ),
                "people2"=> array(
                       "first_name"=>$_POST["first-2"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-2"],
                        )
                )
    )
);



array_push($postArray['people'], 
    array(
                    "people3"=> array(
                       "first_name"=>$_POST["first-2"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-2"],
                        )
    ));



var_dump(json_encode( $postArray ));
```

### Updated code:

```
array_push($postArray["persons"]['people'],
    array("people3"=> array(

                       "first_name"=>$_POST["first-2"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-2"],

    )));
```

Comment: try and change `$postArray['people']` to `$postArray['persons']['people']`

Comment: are are pushing to `$postArray["people"]` instead of `$postArray["persons"]["people"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
$postArray = array(
    "persons" =>  array(
        "person" => array(
                 "i_date"=> $DatabaseDate,
              "i_location"=>$_POST["location"],
              "i_summary"=>$_POST["summary"]
        ),
        "people" => array(
                "people1"=> array(
                       "first_name"=> $_POST["first-1"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-1"]
                      ),
                "people2"=> array(
                       "first_name"=>$_POST["first-2"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-2"],
                        )
                )
    )
);



$postArray["persons"]['people']['people3']=
    array(

                       "first_name"=>$_POST["first-2"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-2"],

    );



var_dump(json_encode( $postArray ));
```

Output in php: print_r :-

```
Array
(
    [persons] => Array
        (
            [person] => Array
                (
                    [i_date] => 
                    [i_location] => 
                    [i_summary] => 
                )

            [people] => Array
                (
                    [people1] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => 
                            [last_name] => 
                        )

                    [people2] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => 
                            [last_name] => 
                        )

                    [people3] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => 
                            [last_name] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

As mentioned by others, that is correct as well.

```
array_push($postArray['persons']['people'], 
    array(
                    "people3"=> array(
                       "first_name"=>$_POST["first-2"],
                       "last_name"=>$_POST["last-2"],
                        )
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but I am not sure why there is "0" between "people2" and "people3".

Comment: Check your code again. There shouldnt be. Or paste your new code for us to verify.

Comment: I checked your code here : http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it worked perfect.